# widget sizing issue: the widget margins are increasing as I increase the minWidth parameter

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to widgets.

The more test I do the less I understand the relationship between the layout.xml and the parameters in the file widget_info.xml.

In the layout file, in studio, everything looks good. But when I position the widget I get the following result:

[image]

So I thought that the minWidth parameter in the widget_info.xml was the parameter to increase (changing it from 100dp to 260dp) but then I get the following result:

[image]

This time it looks ok from a widget size point of view, but the widget margins is pretty bad.

What am I doing wrong?

layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#09C"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img1"
        android:layout_below="@id/img1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/img1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img2"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Not found"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the widget_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/tst_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/tst_widget"
    android:minHeight="32dp"
    android:minWidth="260dp"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```